# How to change the path from which neo4j loads the csvs?

Tags: csv, neo4j

I want to upload nodes from a csv:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///Downloads/template_algorithmes.csv' AS line
MATCH (p:Person {name:'Raf'})
CREATE (al:Algorithm {name: line[1], project:line[2], description:line[3], input:line[4], output:line[5], remark:line[9]}), (p)-[:WORKED_ON]->(al)
```

But it answers:

```
Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/var/lib/neo4j/import/Downloads/template_algorithmes_TEITGEN_raphael.csv
```

Indeed, it is in `/Downloads/` not in `var/lib...` which don't even have a neo4j folder:

```
bash-5.1$ cd /var/lib/
abrt/                  cni/                   dnf/                   games/                 initramfs/             misc/                  PackageKit/            rpm-state/             tpm2-tss/              
AccountsService/       color/                 dnsmasq/               gdm/                   iscsi/                 mlocate/               plymouth/              samba/                 udisks2/               
alsa/                  colord/                docker/                geoclue/               kdump/                 net-snmp/              polkit-1/              selinux/               unbound/               
alternatives/          containerd/            fedora-third-party/    gssproxy/              libvirt/               NetworkManager/        portables/             sss/                   upower/                
authselect/            containers/            flatpak/               hp/                    lockdown/              nfs/                   power-profiles-daemon/ systemd/               xkb/                   
bluetooth/             dbus/                  fprint/                httpd/                 logrotate/             openvpn/               private/               texmf/                 
chrony/                dhclient/              fwupd/                 hyperv/                machines/              os-prober/             rpm/                   tpm/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change it in the neo4j.conf configuration file located in <NEO4J_HOME>/conf. Then ensure to restart/bounce your server.

```
 #default
 #dbms.directories.import=import

 dbms.directories.import=<new location>
```

Comment: Thanks ! And how can I find <NEO4J_HOME> ?